# Click on Menu Navigation animate to that Section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu, when I clicked on each nav, it used to animate to resume on that specific section.

[image]

Somehow, now it didn't do that anymore recently.

What should I check? I see nothing in my console.

Live : https://www.bunlongheng.com/

---

I used JS

This is the snippet

```
$('#main-menu').onePageNav({
    currentClass: "active",
    changeHash: false,
    scrollThreshold: 0.5,
    scrollSpeed: 750,
    filter: "",
    easing: "swing"
});
```

Comment: Your website looks awesome by the way.

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you. I opened up the console on that website and tried it out and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to add this one line of code.

```
$('html').css("scroll-behavior", "smooth");
```

Comment: oh wow... if this works, you're my hero man. I stucked on this like 2 weeks :(

Comment: It worked, I added it and updated my live site with your suggested code; You're my ‍♂️

Comment: Thank-you Benjamin Solomon ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you were using css then you're missing this line
scroll-behavior: smooth;

and if u were using js then please provide a snippet :) thanks for your collaboration.

Comment: I used JS. I updated my post provided what you asked.

Comment: Do you think this could because of the conflict of the jQuery ?

Comment: @cyber8200 yea maybe, if the jquery or the plugin code is not included or missing then there will be a conflict.